# SEO scope for multiple domains hosting on the same IP address

Tags: seo, multiple-domains, shared-hosting

I have multiple domains hosted on a shared hosting plan which provides a single IP address for all domains hosted. I want domains such as:

- www.plumbersinnewyork.com
- www.plumbersinwashington.com
- www.electriciansinnewyork.com

(Domains are for example only)

All these websites are on shared hosting and, on pinging each domain, show the same IP Address.

Will this affect my SEO strategy in any way?

Comment: Even You can have mirroed sites in different ips in different countries around the world and that should  not affect Your SEO strategy. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can create high quality sites, provide great user experience, and take care not to violate any of Google's webmaster guidelines, there is no problem with having multiple sites on a shared host.

With that being said, your sites sound like they could be spammy.   You sound like you are at risk of violating the policy against [doorway pages](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721311?hl=en).  The example domains you give are keyword rich.   If those sites each have little content and funnel users to a main site, then Google is not going to be happy with you.

When you have many domains, you also have to be careful not to create a network of sites that looks like it is designed only to link to each other.   Google has a strict policy against [link schemes](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66356?hl=en).  You probably don't want to link from each of your domains to every other.  You only want to link when the links make sense for users.   See: [Google’s Matt Cutts Says It Is Okay To Link Your Sites Together But In Moderation](http://searchengineland.com/googles-matt-cutts-says-it-is-okay-to-link-your-sites-together-but-in-moderation-157141)

If Google determines that your domains violate the webmaster guidelines in any way, they may penalize all your sites.   Having all your sites hosted on the same IP address is one way that Google could identify all your sites, however it isn't the only way.   Google might also identify your sites by other attributes they may have in common:

- Domain name registrations
- Analytics id
- Advertising accounts
- Affiliate codes
- Search Console account
- Software or modules installed
- Look and feel
- Creation date
- Link profile
- Writing style
- URL structure

Answer (score 5):

Search engines care about content of the web site and not IP addresses. Period. End of story.

Now, if your IP address or domain name is a known spammer; different story.

Comment: Short and sweet! No need for complexity.

Comment: can you provide a source on how a IPv4 known as spam source can affect website ranking provided that its a shared hosting environment?

Comment: @Aurigae Search engines are aware of spam, malware, low quality sites and rank them accordingly. It doesn't matter if they're shared.

Comment: i referred to IPv4 addresses. Its not uncommon that thousands of domains are on one IPv4.

Comment: @Aurigae Neighboring sites, sharing the same IP address, can be affected by spammy neighbors cause spammy IP addresses usually come from bad hosts and bad hosts are also tracked by search engines.

Comment: Is there any valid source on this information?

Comment: @Aurigae Yes. My 12 years of reading about this but, if that's not good enough, you'll have to Google it yourself cause I won't remember them all.

Comment: Thats speculation, not fact - its 2016, IPv4 is limited - a lot of things changed in 12 years - lets stick to facts please.

Comment: @Aurigae As I said, I'm not going to do the work for you. Learn how to Google on your own.

Answer (score 0):

The IPv4 is not relevant to your rankings.

Some hosting provider only allow registration of new IPv4 IP addresses for virtualization, a single website is not a valid reason to book a single IPv4.